# Is there any problem using 18+ words on M&Tv

Tags: discussion, policy

I want to know that is there any problem in using of 18+ words or do we have any limit in using the abusive words.
I mean during description of any movie scene etc can we use 18+ words.

Comment: The SE sites are geared towards 13+ if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The minimum age of stack exchange members is 13, so I would be very careful, especially as different countries and cultures have different expectations for what is acceptable.

However we are clearly here talking about Movies and TV that can be targeted at adult audiences.

I would argue that unless absolutely necessary to ask or answer a question you should try to avoid using too many curse words, or use words that have connotations that are racist, sexist or offensive word relating to sexual orientation or graphical description of sexual activities.

Clearly some times it is difficult to completely avoid such words - but try to be sensitive to the potential audience.  I for one am hard to shock, but in the interests of the wider audience here,  I will recommend edits if I think someone has strayed too far, and close and delete flagrant abuse.

If it is important to a question or answer to have a quote containing such words - then go ahead, *if* it is truly important.

**EDIT**

The StackExchange policy on this is fairly straightforward - [No, its not acceptable.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233)

I would therefore suggest editing out any expletives used in posts - except where it is strictly required for quotations, and even then they could be 'bleeped' in many cases.

Comment: Thanx for the clarification

Comment: *"sexist or gender-ist"* - Isn't that the same anyway?

Comment: @ChristianRau - yes, yes they are - oops - it was nearly a year ago, but I probably meant something relating to sexual orientation.

Comment: This seems to be more of a (personal) guideline than a site policy. Could you please clarify with a more definitive position?

Comment: @coleopterist - Well meta is a 'forum' where we decide the community policy for the site - so this is kind of more than a personal guideline since it is an unchallenged answer to the question.  I have however found a definitive StackExchange policy - which is basically 'No its not acceptable' - so please feel free to remove any you find

Comment: Shouldn't we do what the authorities do for movies and introduce age-related tags that warn the audience of 18+ rated material? There are a lot of movies and TV programs where any discussion would look pretty stupid without the swearing.

Comment: @matt_black - I agree to a point - discussions of 18+ related material is common here.  Judicious use of 'bleeping' out of words, e.g. f***, and spoiler markup with an 18+ warning would allow people to retain the meaning of the text without having it too accessible.  Unlike the authorities, we can't stop (or at least legislate against) people who are under 18 seeing this site!