# Are questions requesting that pornographic films be identified on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, identify

I am curious to know what this site's policy on [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) questions about pornographic films are. I have read the discussion at [Are adult movies (as far as industry, actors, etc... are concerned) on topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263), but that question is 2+ years old now, and doesn't quite address this specific issue.

Note: by "pornographic films", I don't just mean "films that have a sex scene" or "films that are rated NC-17" or even "that stuff that airs on Cinemax late at night" - I mean straight-up 18 USC § 2257 pornography that exists for the sole purpose of titillation.

---

The reason I'm asking is that we're starting to get a trickle of these over at Anime.SE ([here's the latest example](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/17334/1908) [[stack.imgur mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8dmn.png)] - the question itself is clean, but there is porn linked from the question), and I'm interested to know what communities elsewhere on SE think about these questions.

(Update: [here is the corresponding discussion on Anime.SE](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2556/); for reasons beyond my ken, the consensus there appears to be in favor of pornography-identification questions.)

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. On the one hand a well-written question asking for identification seems valid from a technical viewpoint. But given that ID already is the biggest source for crap on the site, I'm not sure we should open that window, too, and I'm afraid what would come through. We had some inappropriate questions, but there the questions were already bad on their own. I'm not sure if we ever had a well-written question looking for a downright porn movie. We certainly never had to deal with this problem on a larger scale.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson not even being ID but other issue also there.

Comment: I actually have had an identify-this-movie question related to a porn movie I happened to see back in the 90's, but have never asked as I felt it inappropriate.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think we should allow questions about pornographic movies here, for one simple reason:

**They don't meet the quality standards of content we discuss on this site.**

I think the same argument applies to porn which applies to web-series: If it is produced on an amateur level or simply does not adhere to our quality standards regarding production or creative level, it should have no place here. ([see this meta discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/do-we-want-web-series-on-topic-here))

This means while proper movies with erotic elements like *Basic Instinct* or *Nymphomaniac* are perfectly fine here, erotic movies where the *story telling or art aspect* of the movie is neglected in favor of showing two people humping (excuse my french) are not on-topic.

This can be a fine line, but in the end it will be up to the community to draw it on each question. But while there are some pornographic movies that are produced on a high level, I am pretty certain that for most cases it will be pretty clear on which side of the line a movie/clip falls.

Comment: You might want to edit out that bit about "excuse my french." I'm well aware it is a common expression in the US, but I doubt native French speakers appreciate the joke.

Answer (score 7):

No. We shouldn’t. Reasons are as

- Pornographic films are made both legally and illegally. Identifying them without promoting illegal content/sites is tough to handle.
- For the most part they contain little in the way of plot and will often be difficult to distinguish from similar films. This will lead to a large portion of such questions being closed as duplicates even when they are not.
- The minimum age of Stack Exchange members is 13[*](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/862/is-there-any-problem-using-18-words-on-mtv), so we should not promote this kind of explicit adult content on SE. Or we need some tag and then age verification before proceeding because people can even include (via embedding or link) videos in questions and answers.

Answer (score 4):

No they should not be allowed. To be a useful identification answer we would need to provide the name of the film and probably a link for reference/confirmation. This leads me to quote [what Jeff Atwood said here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/367).

> No, I don't think we want this, as it would cause us to get globally banned from web filtering software.
>
> **So including adult links, or even mentioning adult sites by name, is explicitly not allowed.**